# Date range associated with a mysql sum becomes invalid in crystal report filter

Tags: mysql, sql, date, crystal-reports, sum

Hi I need help with crystal report! Currently stuck on one part.
In my MySql database I currently have the data for date, paytype, descript and amount. Which currently looks something like this: (Just a small part of the entire db)

```
date        paytype descript        amount
2013-07-01  SD      Student Debit   50.00
2013-08-10  C       Cash            30.00
2013-08-18  SD      Student Debit   100.00
2013-10-01  SD      Student Debit   70.00
2013-11-07  C       Cash            100.00
2013-12-16  G       Credit Card     25.00
```

I want to make it so that it will show the total amount based on each paytype/descript and between some dates. I could make it in mysql query so that it looks like this

```
select 
    `transact`.`date`,
    `transact`.`paytype`,
    `transact`.`descript`,
    sum(`amount`) AS `Total`
from
    `transact`
group by `transact`.`paytype`
```

However, although this does give me what I want, the dates gets stuck with the date the paytype spending starts, e.g it comes out like this:

```
date        paytype descript        amount
2013-07-01  SD      Student Debit   220.00
2013-08-10  C       Cash            130.00
2013-12-16  G       Credit Card     25.00
```

notice how although I do get the total based on each paytype, but the date associate with it is the first date the paytype transaction occured. Now this is where my problem comes...

If I want to do a filtering based by date range to show the types of transactions that occured in between in crystal report.. I am now only left with the option to select these queried dates (and e.g if I choose date for 2013-10-01 which original has a SD paytype transaction, but now it would not show because SD total gets stuck with 2013-7-01).

Is there anyway I can query this but still leaving me all the dates? Or would I be able to do a formula somewhere from crystal report end to fix this problem? Thanks so much and apologize for the long post!

Comment: Why don't you do a query without the sum and instead do the summation by group in the crystal report. Then you can add parameters for start and end dates from the report to fetch the wanted data.

Comment: You are misusing `GROUP BY`. Each column mentioned in your `SELECT` clause needs to be either mentioned in the `GROUP BY` clause or alternatively an aggregate function. You won't be able to troubleshoot this problem until you start using `GROUP BY` correctly. See here. MySQL has a misbegotten extension to `GROUP BY` that helps you get confused. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-extensions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you directly do the grouping then you can't achiwve your requirement instead use the Crystal Reports for grouping. My idea would be:

1. Instead of `groupby` quert use below query in command.

   ```
   select 
   `transact`.`date`,
   `transact`.`paytype`,
   `transact`.`descript`,
   `amount` `Total`
   from
   `transact`
   ```
2. Create two date parameters `Startdate` and `Enddate`.
3. Now create a group in CR with`transact`.`paytype`
4. Place amount and date in detail section.
5. Now take summary in group footer and don't supress detail... dispaly both detail and group.

This should work let me know incase any issue

Comment: thanks! this is actually a better way to do. Because I always like to create a view and query things up for CR first in mysql before connect data. But in the future I should leave these kind of things to the CR end. However, another problem with connecting all data and sum there is that CR takes way too long to load the detailed data since there are about half million data to be queried even if I just print the sums.

Comment: To overcone the second ossue you need to use the `record selection fornula` in crystal reports, whhere you need to mention the condition so that the required number of records are picked from half a million records

Comment: I currently have about half mill records in mysql table and being summed in CR end to display, I know I can filter it based by dates in CR but if everytime I have to filter new date range in select expert it still takes so long to load